# Compare two rows & get the cloumn names where values are different with a common Stored Procedure for multiple table

Tags: java, c#, sql, sql-server, list

I have some tables having 10 to 30 rows. Now I am considering two rows from a table. I need to compare these rows & show the list of column name which values are different. Then I will highlight those columns in my website to show my viewer that these values are changed.

Eample is:

| Id | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | dog | abc | bob | us | fff |
| 2 | 4 | cat | abc | bob | me | fff |

Output :

| Changed_ColumnName |
| --- |
| Col1 |
| Col2 |
| Col5 |

Now the problem is:

1. It is not a good way to compare each & every column & give the output. Again I want to create a common stored procedure for all my tables where I will give the table name & two Column ID & it will do the same. how it can be achieved? because number of table column are not same & column name are not same.
   I saw other questions but they are suggesting to compare every column with other column for one table. No solution for multiple table with single Stored Procedure. Again, if the number column is more, then comparing each column is not a good idea. Can anyone suggest a better way ?
2. The purpose of this work is to show the user of my website about the changes of his previous record & latest record with highlighting the column that are changed. So, is it a good way to do it in above SQL approach? or taking two record as list of model & compare them in backend using C# or java will be a better solution ? If yes, then how ? without comparing each & every column.

Comment: When comparing rows from different tables how do you know which pair of columns (named differently) to compare? What are the rules to compare columns of different type? Your task lacks a good deal of specifications.

Comment: As I am always comparing  two rows from same table at a time, column will be same. so I will check based on column name.

I am not considering comparing rows from different tables.

Comment: "I want to create a common stored procedure for all my tables " This kind of thing usually ends bad.

Comment: So, I need to write different different Stored Procedure for each table ? @ZoharPeled

Comment: Not necessarily. If you know your way around dynamic SQL it can be done using a single procedure for all tables, but it's probably not going to be very easy. You can take some ideas from my blog post entitled [T-SQL CRUD procedures auto-generator](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2020/02/06/t-sql-crud-procedures-auto-generator/). Having said that, you should know it would be simpler to write a different procedure for each table.

Answer (score 3):

One method would be to use a `CASE` expression to do the comparison, and then unpivot (I use a `VALUES` table construct) to get the desired results:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT CASE R1.Col1 WHEN R2.Col1 THEN NULL ELSE 'Col1' END AS Col1,
           CASE R1.Col2 WHEN R2.Col2 THEN NULL ELSE 'Col2' END AS Col2,
           CASE R1.Col3 WHEN R2.Col3 THEN NULL ELSE 'Col3' END AS Col3,
           CASE R1.Col4 WHEN R2.Col4 THEN NULL ELSE 'Col4' END AS Col4,
           CASE R1.Col5 WHEN R2.Col5 THEN NULL ELSE 'Col5' END AS Col5,
           CASE R1.Col6 WHEN R2.Col6 THEN NULL ELSE 'Col6' END AS Col6
    FROM dbo.YourTable R1
         JOIN dbo.YourTable R2 ON R2.ID = 2
    WHERE R1.ID = 1)
SELECT V.ColumnName
FROM CTE C
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(Col1, 'Col1'),
                        (Col2, 'Col2'),
                        (Col3, 'Col3'),
                        (Col4, 'Col4'),
                        (Col5, 'Col5'),
                        (Col6, 'Col6'))V(ColumnValue,ColumnName)
WHERE V.ColumnValue IS NOT NULL;
GO
```

If you have `NULL` values this won't work, you'd need to adjust the `CASE` expressions to check the `NULL` values are different, but this should get you on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

You can approach this using aggregation and some conditional logic.  Assuming the values are never `NULL`, you can put the values in a list as:

```
select concat_ws(',',
                 (case when min(col1) <> max(col1) then 'col1' end),
                 (case when min(col2) <> max(col2) then 'col2' end),
                 (case when min(col3) <> max(col3) then 'col3' end),
                 (case when min(col4) <> max(col4) then 'col4' end),
                 (case when min(col5) <> max(col5) then 'col5' end)
                ) as Changed_ColumnName
from t
where id in (1, 2);
```

Note:  This works regardless of the types of the columns (well, assuming `min()` and `max()` work which is true of most data types.  An approach that uses unpivoting assumes that the columns all have the same (or compatible) types.

Comment: It is working regardless of type. Great. For NULL value, we can use ISNULL for the column that can be NULL